# Zipping content from another users dir with out the root dir being included

Tags: sudo, zip

I have the following dir structure.

/home/bradley/data/ {whole bunch of files and dirs}

I want to zip up the content but not include /home/bradley in the archive. So I have tried this.

`cd /home/bradley/ && sudo zip -FS -r -b /tmp /home/0-backup/users/bradley.zip *`

This does work. However, the script that runs this command is run as a different user with sudo privileges.  You can't do `sudo cd /home/bradley`.  Not permitted.

I tried `sudo -D /home/bradley zip -FS -r -b /tmp /home/0-backup/users/bradley.zip *` but I get the error `sudo: you are not permitted to use the -D option with /usr/bin/zip`.

I am not sure where to go to next. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ok, took reading the man page of sudo... here is the correct way to do it.

sudo sh -c "cd /home/bradley; zip -FS -r -b /tmp /home/0-backup/users/brdley.zip *"